# PowerShell - Limit the search to only one OU

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-management, organizational-unit

Ive got this cmdlet and I'd like to limit the results to only one OU:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter  {(Enabled -eq $false)} | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Disabled Users*') }
```

Now Ive tried to use

```
-searchbase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

But if I use `-SearchBase` I get this error:

```
Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'searchb
ase'.
At line:1 char:114
+ Get-ADUser -Filter  {(Enabled -eq $false)} | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notli
ke '*Disabled Users*') } -searchbase <<<<  "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBi
   ndingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.WhereObjectCommand
```

What Im trying to do is to get all the disabled users from a specific OU, BUT, there is an OU INSIDE that FirstOU that I want to exclude: the "Disabled Users" OU.

as you might have guessed I want to find disabled users in a specific OU that are not in the "Disabled Users" OU inside that OU.

my structure:

```
Forest
   FirstOU
      Users,groups,etc...
      Disabled Users OU
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-SearchBase` parameter has to be used with Get-ADUser, not Where-Object (aliased by ?). This should work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $false)} -SearchBase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com" | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Disabled Users*') }
```

Comment: -1 Most efficient method of searching only a single OU is using `-SearchScope` as in [Thorfinn Thomassen's](http://serverfault.com/users/327631) [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/601797/powershell-limit-the-search-to-only-one-ou/#743656) in this question. Using Where-Object makes the Get-AdUser return the nested OU as well whose contents should end up being all eliminated by end of processing.

Comment: Also, your answer contains a subset of the same information as [Hopelessn00b's](http://serverfault.com/users/118258) [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/601797/powershell-limit-the-search-to-only-one-ou/#601801). Suggest your answer be removed to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to limit the search to one `OU` is using SearchScope:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter  {(Enabled -eq $false)} -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

Comment: +1 For use of `SearchScope` to limit search to that first OU, and not spend time parsing the nested one.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to put the `-SearchBase` before the `-Filter`.

```
Get-ADUser -searchbase "ou=FirstOU,dc=domain,dc=com" -Filter {(Enabled -eq $false)} | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Disabled Users*') }
```

Gets around the problem of having to use `-SearchBase` with `Get-ADUser`, and not `Where-Object` (`?` is aliased to `Where-Object` in PowerShell) by running the `Where-Object` after you've already passed your `-SearchBase` to `Get-ADUser`.